# trying to $emit twice inside method with asynchronous logic

Tags: vue.js

in my method i call `$emit` twice but only the first attempt - `reportDownloadStarted` works, and if i comment out the first attempt, only then the second one - `reportDownloadFinished` works. here is my method:

```
downloadReport() {
  this.$emit("reportDownloadStarted", true);
  const endpoint = this.getEndpoint();

  const someDummyData = []
  reportsRequest({
    url: endpoint,
    method: "post",
    data: someDummyData 
  })
    .then(res => {
      let link = `${process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL}/${res.data}`;
      if (res.status === 200) {
        window.open(link, "_blank").focus();
        this.$emit("reportDownloadFinished", true);
      }
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
      this.$emit("reportDownloadFinished", false);
    });
}
```

any idea what is causing this behavior ? thanks

Comment: Define "works". Is it the event handler that doesn't behave as expected? How so?

Comment: maybe works can be replaced with "taking place" "being executed" or "emitted" to make it clearer